# open a sheet checkbox is checked with vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

how I can check if a checkbox is selected ? 
And after selecting a checkbox for example **"a"** (in my example) I want to open a excel sheet.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you all.

Comment: What code do you have so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: hi @RikSportel , i tried: `if Checkbox1= True Then MsgBox("true")` . I only tried it with a msgBox. But this does not work. I get the message _object required_ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UserForm module you can just place the following code, when your CheckBox is named "CheckBox1":

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Visible = True
    Else
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

This will make "Sheet1" visible when it's checked and invisible when unchecked.
If you name your checkbox differently, you'll see that if you double click the checkbox in the Userform Design, the VBE will already come up with

```
Private Sub CheckBoxName_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: thx it works :-). I have a further question. After selecting the checkbox "a" (in my example) it should automatically open a file (its always the same file). If I always generate a new file this will waste a lot of space. _for example I have a file on my desk named **test.xlsx** and after selecting my checkbox **a** the file **test.xlsx** opens automatically._ Thx for help

Comment: One question per topic mate, but just use 'Workbooks.Open("somepath\somefile.xlsx")'